# SSRS Report not returning data

Tags: reporting-services

I'm battling with a strange one.  I've created a report using Visual Studio and deployed it successfully (so I thought).  When I run it from within Visual Studio it displays data perfectly.  But when I try and run it from online directly it allows me to select the parameters, it goes through the motions but returns no data.  What could the issue be?  I tried refreshing the fields in the Query Editor but this didn't work either.

Comment: What security credentials are you using on the server?  Does that account have access to the required data?  This may also be a [double hop authentication](https://redmondmag.com/Articles/2010/08/23/Reporting-Services-Double-Hop-Authentication.aspx?Page=1) issue.

Comment: I'm using Windows authentication.  I installed reporting services on my local machine but it accesses data on one of our DB servers.  My windows account has full access to the database server and is a system administrator on my local machine.  I just find it strange that I can run it within Visual Studio (it opens up the web interface) but not directly from the reports directory.  I've tried everything.

Comment: Do you have dates on the report? Has something like this happen to me recently. My report was getting mixed up between american and normal dates.

Comment: Nope.  There are three input parameters, two are integers and the other a varchar.  :(

Comment: It just got weirder.  Though the report screen is blank, if I export it to PDF it exports the data.

Comment: Debbie, try downloading SQL Server Report Builder. Open it with that and save it through there. I've experienced some weirdness building reports in Visual Studio.

Comment: @DebbieDippenaar Are you using Chrome (Or anything other than IE?)  Chrome will run the report, but render blank, hence your export works but you see nothing on screen.  Try running in IE.